# Difference between install.packages() and library()

Tags: r

Per my understanding, `ggplot2` is part of the `tidyverse` package.
If, after installing `tidyverse`, I load it through `library()`, then do I need to also load individual packages such as `ggplot2` as well?

I've seen my Coursera instructor load the entire `tidyverse` and sometimes just individual packages.

Also, I noticed some arguments need to be enclosed in quotes while others do not. For example, install.packages() needs "", but library() doesn't.

Is there a list which shows which arguments need to be enclose in quotation marks that I can refer to?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no list that tells you whether arguments need quotation marks. Just use `?<function-name>` (e.g., `?library`) in the R console to get the help file. In the help file it should tell you if the argument needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The `tidyverse` is an overarching package which includes `ggplot2` along with many others like `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may attach either all or only a small subset of the `tidyverse` packages.

If you've already loaded in `tidyverse`, yes, `ggplot2` would be redundant. It's good practice to only load in packages you're actually going to use because there's the possibility of multiple packages having identically named functions that would require you to preface them with `<package_name>::` to distinguish them.

`install.packages()` requires quotes for the library in question, `library()` does not.